# React.createRef is not a function in react-rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, reactjs

A am using react-rails gem in my ruby on rails project. I try to add reference to my DOM element. This is my component:

```
class NewItem extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.name = React.createRef();
  }
  handleClick() {
    var name  = this.name.value;
    console.log(name);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input ref={this.name} placeholder='Enter the name of the item' />
        <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Submit</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
};
```

When i try to load the page in browser i have this message in console:
`TypeError: React.createRef is not a function. (In 'React.createRef()', 'React.createRef' is undefined)`.

Comment: are  u using latest version of react?

Comment: @GautamNaik yes

Answer (score 13):

update react to 16.3 
React.createRef() this API is added  on react 16.3
checkout this https://github.com/facebook/react/pull/12162

Answer (score -2):

Try changing this

```
  handleClick() {
    var name  = this.name.value;
    console.log(name);
  }
```

to

```
  handleClick = () => {
    var name  = this.name.current.value;
    console.log(name);
  }
```

Dont use ref for getting value of input. Use this method

```
class NameForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {value: ''};

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({value: event.target.value});
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    alert('A name was submitted: ' + this.state.value);
    event.preventDefault();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <label>
          Name:
          <input type="text" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange} />
        </label>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
      </form>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Hello @GautamNaik Thank you for your answer. When i try to change my handleClick function to your then i have this error: `SyntaxError: unknown: Unexpected token (7:14) 5 | } 6 | > 7 | handleClick = () => { | ^ 8 | var name = this.name.current.value; 9 | console.log(name); 10 | }` When i change only `var name = this.name.current.value;` then i have the same error like in top post. Your method works good, but what if i need reference in another place?

Comment: u can use props if u want to send the value to other components

Comment: No, i ask about reference. I can't create reference for any DOM element. How can i fix it? Use the reference is ideology of React.js.